# Creating a node.js application to consume an API and print the response on to an HTML

Tags: html, api, node.js

First of all, i am very much new to node.js and web services.

I am working on something which requires me to get the temperature from openweather.org API and serve the result in a HTTP.

The api is

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/name?q=London

And I would like to save the city name, temperature and degree in an HTML in the following format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Current Weather</h1>

<hr/>
<strong id="city">{{city}}</strong>
<span id="temperature">{{temperature}}</span>
<span id="unit">{{unit}}</span>
<hr/>
<small>last update: <span id="lastupdate">{{datetime}}</span></small>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that? any help.

Comment: Those are plenty questions at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1: create a simple node app to perform the api request and return the output to the console. Use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to make your life easy

step 2: use a template engine like the one in [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or others to merge api output with above html template.
For example:

```
var apiResult = JSON.parse(the_result_of_api_call);
var template = '<strong id="city"><%= list[0].name %></strong>';
var output = _.template(template)(apiResult);
```

step 3: create a [node express website](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) to combine the above and do a response.send(mergedoutput).

Comment: I am finding it a bit difficult on how to use template engine of underscore to merger my api output? Any help or any sample code, would be really helpful.

Comment: I've added a templating example

Answer (score 2):

Visit [http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/http.html#http.request) for more information.

```
        var options = {
          host: url,
          port: 80,
          path: '/resource?id=foo&bar=baz',
          method: 'POST'
        };

        http.request(options, function(res) {
          console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
          console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
          res.setEncoding('utf8');
          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
          });
        }).end();
```

Above block of code will help you retrieve data from other website.

You will need to have a look at `backbone.js` and `underscore.js` if you want to render data in a (similar)fashion which is mentioned in the question.

You can see one example which has similar stuff : [backbone.js with node.js](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/)